# How do I edit the bootstrap to fit the screen on my phone?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I made an application that theoretically should be responsive. I tested it in the browser and it worked normal, but when I test it on the phone, the screen does not adjust.

This is the site:
http://transparencia.camarajaboatao.pe.gov.br

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say that it theoretically should be responsive, what do you mean? Did you make it responsive? If so, how? Show your code. If not, why do you think it's theoretically responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't look on the source just checked it in my android, but if you talk about the buttons size, you can change the size with media queries. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Example to your case:
1. Add class to the buttons you want. Lets call it "kaftor".
2. In your css file, add:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .kaftor { width: 45%; }
}
```

Hope it helps!

You can find practical more examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: @Danilo Rodrigues why did you change you call? Was this answer didn't solve it??